# get user input and print into file

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, tie

I would like to add a feature in below code to check if both fruit and info input provided by user in cmd exist in the file. Meanwhile to fullfill 3 requirements below, first and second are completed with code below.

- If the fruit provided in cmd line not exist in file, then add it in with the info provided.
- If the fruit provided in cmd already exist in file, then add in info provided into it. Info 1 is mapping fruit1
- If both fruit and info provided in cmd already exist in file, skip it

cmd: `<script> -fruit apple,orange,jackfruit -info y,c,a`

File example:

```
apple
     x
     y

orange
     a
     b
```

Expected output (Since apple and y already in the file, skip it):

```
    apple
         x
         y

    orange
         a
         b
         c

    jackfruit
         a
```

Code:

```
   use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Tie::File;
    my $help=0;
    my $info;
    my $fruit;
    use Getopt::Long;

if (! GetOptions(
     "fruit=s" => \$fruit,
     "info=s" => \$info,  
)){
  print "\nEntered Arguments are not enough!\nPlease Use Switch '-help' or '-h' For More Information.\n";
   exit;
}

my $split_info;
my $split_fruit;
my @split_info = split(',', $info);
my @split_fruit = split(',', $fruit);

my %new_data;
@new_data{@split_fruit}=@split_info;


tie my @file, 'Tie::File', "/nfs/site/disks/ipg_da_00003/ip7nm/sungyuan/script/regression_indicator/testing/2022.12.SP1/config.txt" or die $!;

for (0 .. $#file) {
    next if /^\s/;

    if (exists $new_data{$file[$_]}) {
      splice @file, $_ + 1, 0, "\t$new_data{$file[$_]}\n";
      # Delete our current key/value pair from the hash
      delete $new_data{$file[$_]};
    }
}

# For each key left in the hash...
for (keys %new_data) {
  # Push two new lines into our tied file array
  # (This adds new lines to the end of the file)
  push @file, "$_\n", "\t$new_data{$_}\n";
}
```

Comment: To clarify your question, could you give an example of the input file `config.txt`?

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this later

Comment: A question: if the file already contains "x" for apple, and you add another "x" for apple, your current script will give two lines with "x" for apple, right?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yup right.

Comment: Is this intended or do you want to keep the info values unique? Such that if adding a second "x" for apple it should only keep the first "x"

Comment: the info values will be a unique path in this case, I am just using simple "x" as example. The concept is to precheck the file whether any existing info for respective fruit, if no, add the info values into the file (under respective fruit)

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear if the info values should be unique or not. Anyway I think this problem is more easily solved using a json file than using a custom file format. Here is an example using JSON input file format:

**config.json**

```
{
   "apple" : [
      "x",
      "y"
   ],
   "orange" : [
      "a",
      "b",
   ]
}
```

Then using this Perl script to read and modify the JSON input file:

```
use Object::Pad;
{

    my $self = Main->new(config_fn => 'config.json');
    $self->parse_commandline();
    $self->read_config();
    $self->update_config();
    $self->save_config();
}

class Main;
use feature qw(say);
use Getopt::Long;
use JSON;

field $_config_fn :param;
field %_config;
field @_fruits;
field @_info;

method parse_commandline() {
    my $fruit;
    my $info;
    my $msg1 = "Unable to parse command line options. ";
    my $msg2 = "Please use switch '-help' or '-h' for more information.";
    if (! GetOptions(
        "fruit=s" => \$fruit,
        "info=s" => \$info,
    )){
        die "${msg1} ${msg2}\n";
    }
    die "${msg1}: fruit parameter not given. ${msg2}\n" if !defined $fruit;
    die "${msg1}: info parameter not given. ${msg2}\n" if !defined $info;
    @_fruits = split ",", $fruit;
    @_info = split ",", $info;
    die "${msg1}: fruit and info parameters must have the same number of items. ${msg2}\n"
        if @_fruits != @_info;
}

method read_config() {
    my $fn = $_config_fn;
    open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do {local $/; <$fh>};
    %_config = %{ decode_json( $str ) };
    close $fh;
}

method save_config() {
    my $fn = $_config_fn;
    my $json_text = to_json( \%_config, {utf8 => 1, pretty => 1});
    # TODO: remember to take a backup of this file first!!
    open (my $fh, ">", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $json_text;
    close $fh;
    say "Updated $fn";
}

method update_config() {
    for my $i (0..$#_fruits) {
        my $fruit = $_fruits[$i];
        my $info = $_info[$i];
        my %infos = map {$_ => 1} @{$_config{$fruit}};
        $infos{$info}++;
        @{$_config{$fruit}} = sort keys %infos;
    }
}
```

If you prefer the original file format, you could try this instead:

```
use Object::Pad;
{

    my $self = Main->new(config_fn => 'config.txt');
    $self->parse_commandline();
    $self->read_config();
    $self->update_config();
    $self->save_config();
}

class Main;
use feature qw(say);
use Getopt::Long;

field $_config_fn :param;
field %_config;
field @_cmdline_fruits;
field @_cmdline_info;
field @_config_fruits;

method parse_commandline() {
    my $fruit;
    my $info;
    my $msg1 = "Unable to parse command line options. ";
    my $msg2 = "Please use switch '-help' or '-h' for more information.";
    if (! GetOptions(
        "fruit=s" => \$fruit,
        "info=s" => \$info,
    )){
        die "${msg1} ${msg2}\n";
    }
    die "${msg1}: fruit parameter not given. ${msg2}\n" if !defined $fruit;
    die "${msg1}: info parameter not given. ${msg2}\n" if !defined $info;
    @_cmdline_fruits = split ",", $fruit;
    @_cmdline_info = split ",", $info;
    die "${msg1}: fruit and info parameters must have the same number of items. ${msg2}\n"
        if @_cmdline_fruits != @_cmdline_info;
}

method read_config() {
    my $fn = $_config_fn;
    open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my %config;
    my $fruit;
    my @fruits;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        next if $line !~ /\S/;  #skip empty lines
        if ($line !~ /^\t/) { # a line that does not start with a tab is a fruit
            $fruit = $line;
            push @_config_fruits, $fruit;  # use an array to record the ordering of fruits
        }
        else {  # assume it is a info line
            my $info = $line =~ s/^\t//r;  # remove initial tab character
            push @{$_config{$fruit}}, $info;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

method save_config() {
    my $fn = $_config_fn;
    # TODO: remember to take a backup of this file first!!
    open (my $fh, ">", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    for my $fruit (@_config_fruits) {
        say $fh $fruit;
        for my $info (@{$_config{$fruit}}) {
            say $fh "\t", $info;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
    say "Updated $fn";
}

method update_config() {
    for my $i (0..$#_cmdline_fruits) {
        my $fruit = $_cmdline_fruits[$i];
        my $info = $_cmdline_info[$i];
        my %infos = map {$_ => 1} @{$_config{$fruit}}; # use hash to make info items unique
        $infos{$info}++;
        @{$_config{$fruit}} = sort keys %infos;  #keep the info items in sorted order
    }
}
```

Comment: ++ for use of Object::Pad :-)

Comment: Yes I like it, also looking forward to 5.38 with feature class!

Comment: @HåkonHægland, not sure if you have solution for using custom file format as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use a hash of array to approach your question
The arrangement for apple,orange,jackfruit will messed up since I store in a hash, but you can try to assign weightage for each keys inside the hash and loop through it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my $path = '/home/liew/perl_programming/module/fruit.txt';
my %hash_of_array;
my $fruits;
my $info;
my @info;
my $key;
my %hash_input;
my @deref_arr;

GetOptions(
'fruits=s'=>\$fruits,
'info=s'=>\$info
);

print "Not enough argument\n" if (!$fruits|!$info);

open (my $fh, '<', "$path") or die "Can't open file:$!";

while (my $line =<$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^(\w+)$/) {
        $key = $1;
    }
    else {
       push (@{$hash_of_array{$key}} ,$line); 
    }
}
close ($fh);

my @splited_fruit = split(',', $fruits);
my @splited_info = split(',', $info);

@hash_input{@splited_fruit} = @splited_info;

foreach my $key (keys %hash_input) {

if (exists $hash_of_array{$key}) {
@deref_arr = @{$hash_of_array{$key}};

    if (!grep(/$hash_input{$key}/, @deref_arr)) {

    push(@{$hash_of_array{$key}}, "\t$hash_input{$key}");

    }
}

else {

    $hash_of_array{$key} = "\t$hash_input{$key}";
}

}

print Dumper \%hash_of_array, "\n";

sub write_file {
foreach my $key (keys %hash_of_array) {

print "$key\n";
my $value = $hash_of_array{$key};
if (ref($value) eq "ARRAY") {
    foreach my $element (@{ $hash_of_array{$key} }) {
        print "$element\n";

        }
}

else {

  print "$hash_of_array{$key}\n";
}

}
}

#write to file

open (my $fh_w, '>', "$path") or die "Can't write to file:$!";

select $fh_w;
write_file;
select STDOUT;

close ($fh_w);
```